# EF Core overwrite mechanic to send commands to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to use EF Core for my application but instead that EF Core should send a SQL command onto a datbase it should just simply send it to another application which will care about multi-tenancy and choosing the right database (tennant) for this command.

So is there a way to overwrite the main point in EF Core where the command is allready generated and WOULD be now send into the given database and instead of sending it into that, just do things?

Comment: Why are you trying to do that inside the ORM? That's completely outside an ORM's job - Mapping Objects to Relational data. You shouldn't even be using an ORM if you want to send commands to a different service. The tools meant to send commands to other services are HTTP APIs, brokers like RabbitMQ or Kafka, Service busses like NServiceBus or MassTransit

Comment: The basic background is, that we have a multi tennant app with a silo isolation (each tennant a single db) which means I have to handle 10K of databases with 1 mikroservice. The worries about that is connection pooling, live cicle of a connection and so on - the idea to solve that is to have each microservice let send the command to a tennant service which handles the connections etc.

Comment: EF Core *can* be used in multi-tenant applications and save data directly to the correct database. The [EF Core Multitenancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy) page explains some of the options: Configuration can be used to load different connection strings per tenant. Global query filters can be used to filter by a discriminator column. Separate schemas can be used by changing the target table

Comment: `the idea to solve that is to have` you're assuming there's any problem to solve in the first place. There isn't. Connection pooling works per connection *string* and user. The connection lifecycle is controlled by EF Core and already works in a highly scalable manner - a connection is *only* opened when data needs to be read or persisted.

Comment: The disconnected operations of EF Core (and ADO.NET in general) and optimistic concurrency allow orders of magnitude better scaling than using explicit transactions.

Comment: As for *scope*, in a web app that's a single request, which means each DbContext instance by default will be used only for a single request. I assume the tenant won't change during that request. [Switching tenants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy#switching-tenants) withing a single request is still possible by generating transient instances of DbContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multitenancy is already supported in EF Core. The options are described in the [Multi-tenancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy) page in the docs.

In this case, it appears a different database per tenant is used. Assuming there's a way/service that can return who the tenant is, a DbContext can use [a different connection string for each tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy#multiple-databases-and-connection-strings). Assuming there's a way/service to retrieve the current tenant name, eg `ITenantService`, the DbContext constructor can use it to load a different connection string per tenant. The entire process could be abstracted behind eg an `ITenantConnectionService`, but the docs show how this is done explicitly.

The context constructor will need the tenant name and access to configuration :

```
public ContactContext(
    DbContextOptions<ContactContext> opts,
    IConfiguration config,
    ITenantService service)
    : base(opts)
{
    _tenantService = service;
    _configuration = config;
}
```

Each time a new DbContext instance is created, the connection string is loaded from configuration based on the tenant's name:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var tenant = _tenantService.Tenant;
    var connectionStr = _configuration.GetConnectionString(tenant);
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionStr);
}
```

This is enough to use a different database per tenant.

**Scope and lifecycle**

These aren't a concern when a DbContext is used as a Scoped or Transient service.

By default `AddDbContext` registers DbContexts as scoped services. The scope in a web application is a single request. Once a request is processed, any DbContext instances created are disposed.

**Connection Pooling**

Connection pooling isn't a concern either. First of all, a DbContext doesn't represent a database connection. It's a disconnected Unit-of-Work. A connection is *only* opened when the context needs to load data from the database or persist changes when `SaveChanges` is called. If `SaveChanges` isn't called, nothing gets persisted. No connections remain open between loading and saving.

Consistency is maintained using optimistic concurrency. When the data is saved EF Core checks to see if the rows being stored have changed since the time they were loaded. In the rare case that some other application/request changed the data, EF Core throws a DbConcurrencyException and the application has to decide what to do with the changed data.

This way, there's no need for a database transaction and thus no need for an open connection. When optimistic concurrency was introduced in ... the late 1990s, application scalability increased by *several* (as in more than 100, if not 1000) orders of magnitude.

Connection pooling is used to eliminate the cost of opening and closing connections. When `DbConnection.Close()` is called, the actual network connection isn't terminated. The connection is reset and placed in a pool of connections that can be reused.

That's a driver-level feature, not something controlled by EF Core. Connections are pooled by *connection string* and in the case of Windows Authentication, per user. This eliminates the chance of a connection meant for one user getting used by another one.

Connection pooling is controlled by ADO.NET and the database provider. Some drivers allow connection pooling while others don't. In those that do support it, it can be turned off using keywords in the connection string or driver settings.

Answer (score 1):

[EF Core Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors) allow you to do just that:

```cs
public class QueryCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override async ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(
        DbCommand command,
        CommandEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var resultReader = await SendCommandToAnotherAppAsync(command);

        return InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>.SuppressWithResult(resultReader);
    }

    private Task<DbDataReader> SendCommandToAnotherAppAsync(DbCommand command)
    {
        // TODO: Actual logic.
        Console.WriteLine(command.CommandText);

        return Task.FromResult<DbDataReader>(null!);
    }
}
```

Make sure to override other methods like `ScalarExecuting`, `NonQueryExecuting`, sync and async variants.

Comment: Just because it's possible doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: Wow thats beauftiful, thank you :)

Comment: The `Actual Logic` part is an entire complex and quirky service that depends on the communication method with the other application, parsing the contents of `DbCommand`, converting it to something the other application understands.

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper it's not. Why don't you just *call* that application directly ? Or use EF Core's multitenancy mechanism? How are you going to parse the *parameters* of that DbCommand and send them elsewhere? Or the SQL ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it could be simply a different DbConnection, as the question states. No need for parsing anything. Or you could send the command and parameters to another service, which will re-create DbCommand and send it somewhere. Again, no need for parsing.

Comment: EF Core can [already handle different connections per tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy#multiple-databases-and-connection-strings). `Configuration.GetConnectionString(tenantName)` in `OnConfiguring` will load a different connection per tenant. The config source doesn't have to be `appsettings.json`, it can easily be a database, some other file, a configuration service

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's great, you could add it as another answer! Instead of spreading panic in the comments :)

Comment: Pointing out that the hard parts are missing isn't spreading panic. How will that `DbCommand` make it over HTTP to another service?

Comment: DbCommand is made of `CommandText`, `CommandTimeout`, `CommandType` and `Parameters`. No problem to serialize in any format. Why do you mention HTTP? It is nowhere in the question, and it is not an efficient service communication method.